# Sending Sms with swift ios

Tags: ios, swift

its not working properly and throws below error,
'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target'

thanks in advance

```
@IBAction func sms(_ sender: Any)
{
    var messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self

    messageVC.body = "Enter a message";
    messageVC.recipients = ["Enter tel-nr"]

    self.present(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)


}

func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult)
{
    switch (result)
    {
    case MessageComposeResult.cancelled:
        print("Message was cancelled")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResult.failed:
        print("Message failed")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResult.sent:
        print("Message was sent")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: And your code is... ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51985416/edit) your question and include the code there

Comment: Note that you should do `if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText(){}` before attempting to show it. Which line is causing the error ?

Comment: if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText())
        {
            let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            controller.body = "Message Body"
            controller.recipients = [phoneNumber.text] as? [String]
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

Comment: written the above code it is not even entering into that condition

Comment: Are you allowed to write a SMS on that device? Which device is it?

Comment: @LearnAsMuchAsYouCan _Again_, please edit your question and include the code there

Answer (score 0):

Try on a real device with sms capability, not the iOS Simulator.